# Anchor Peer updation fails, after updating channel configurarion in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Initially I had one organization in the channel, I have added one more organization to the channel by following the link https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html. **After adding the new organization to the channel, when I try to update anchor peer  it's throwing an error an error saying**
"Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key [Group]  /Channel/Application at version 1, but got version 2"

Cannot update anchor peer using peer channel update.

peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f Org1MSPanchors.tx

Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key [Group]  /Channel/Application at version 1, but got version 2

Had been lost in this for too long.

Any kind of help is appreciated..